# how to parameterize query timeout in Copy data activity for full load and incremental load in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

In copy data I have query timeout as 2hrs I want to parameterize the query timeout for Full load and Delta load.

**For Full load query timeout should be 2 hrs
For delta load query timeout should be 45mins**

Comment: How would you know when you are executing the activity for full load or delta load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can achieve your requirement through either of the two following. You need to have a condition to check whether the load is full or incremental.
- Now you can use if condition activity to check this. You can use dynamic content to select the value for query timeout directly in the copy data activity.
- The following is an example how you can achieve this. I have a parameter with its value as `full or incremental`.
  [image]
- Now use dynamic content with condition something similar to `@{if(equals(pipeline().parameters.load,'full'),120,45)}`

[image]

- For this to work, you need to know what the particular load would be before executing the copy data activity.